# Thread needs to check if else continuously

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void run()
{
    if (flag)
    {
        infinite Loop... 
    }   
    else
    {
        infinite Loop... 
    }   
}
```

In my thread there is if else statement which executes based on `flag`. Here my `flag` is not static and changes dynamically while executing the program. Every time the `flag` value changes I want the if-else condition to be checked. Suppose my `flag` is `false` it will execute the else part. Now my `flag` changes to `true` then it should come out of else and execute if part. How can this be implemented ???

Comment: There is infinite loop in if and else how do i come out of it ??? If i come out then only i can check while condition ....

Comment: Can you insert a `break` at the relevant parts?

Answer (score 3):

If a thread enters an infinite loop without any exit condition then you have no way to make it change its behaviour unless you force its interruption.

Given that you can just move the `if/else` outside:

```
public void run() {
  while (!finished) {
    if (flag) {
      .. true loop iteration ..
    }
    else {
      .. false loop iteration ..
    }
  }
}
```

Mind that you want `flag` to be `volatile` so that thread can use its most recent value. In addition variables which can't be changed dynamically are `final`, not `static`, which has a different meaning.

If you are forced to have separated infinite loops just place a condition in there:

```
public void run() {
  while (!finished) {
    while (flag) {
      .. true loop iteration ..
    }
    while (!flag) {
      .. false loop iteration ..
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is a thread issue. From your verbal description, it sounds like you want to do this:

```
while (true) {
    while (flag) {
        // first infinite loop body
    }
    while (!flag) {
        // second infinite loop body
    }
}
```

That will execute the first loop as long as the flag is `true`. As soon as the flag becomes `false`, the first loop will exit and the second loop with start.

Comment: What guarantees you have that after exiting the first loop, `flag` is not set back to `true` before entering the second loop?

Comment: Good point, @Jack. Considering these will be separate threads, it could be tricky.

Comment: @Jack - Good point! I misread the original post. I updated the code to handle `flag` switching back and forth. Of course, there's a race condition, but if it is important, then OP needs something that provides more control than a simple flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean flag = true; 
    while (flag) 
{       // if true
         //Statements executed for true
        }
    while (!flag) 
{   // if false
        //Statements executed for false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(finished == false)
{
    if(flag == true)
    {
        while(flag == true  && finished == false)
        {
                //do if
        }
    }
    else
    {  
        while(flag == false && finished == false)
        {
            // do else
        }

    }
}
```

`finished` is another `boolean` you have which tells to stop the thread.